# Using the jQuery spritely plugin's .pan() to skip in between a defined space

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

OK, sorry for the awkward title!

It's kind of a unique situation in my opinion.

So basically, with the jQuery plugin Spritely, it's possible to call a .pan() method/action which allows you to (self-explanatory really) pan something across the screen.

I currently have three video game scenes panning from left to right and visa versa in the background of my page, behind my content.

Now, I was thinking it would be cool, that instead of when part of the panning image is passed behind my content `<div>`s, it would skip to the other side, without going behind the `<div>`s.

I would also like for sprites to be able to go from the left side to the right side, so it would be nicer if it wasn't two separate instances of the plugin.  I'm open to any suggestions though!

Is there an easy way to specify this?

Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer below with some example code

Comment: Think about switching your code into html5, you can do some cool stuff with that canvas.

Comment: @Inrbob, let me check it out.
@ user257493 I like that idea, do you suggest it replace, or modify certain parts, if modify, which ones?

Comment: html5 and css3 would make this easier but be aware that neither are well supported, especially in IE. You'd need to integrate javascript that adds support to all your existing code. Either way could be a fair amount of work so I'd decide which route you'd like to take before you double your workload. Finally, have you investigated other plugins?

Comment: Yeah, well, the only other plugin I've considered is GameQuery because I would really love to make it interactive.  However, this would require a LOT of work especially with the background problem.  I think for now, I'll either leave it, or go with the route you suggested in your answer.

Comment: @user257493: Saying you should just use HTML5 is such a useless suggestion since platform constraints were not described in the original post. HTML5 is nice, but it's not the solution to all browser/graphics issues.

Answer (score 4):

because you are moving images I doubt there is an easy way to to do this other than using two instances of the plugin. Both moving the same way but one on the left of the content, one on the right, and timed so that it appears to be just one reel.

You may not want to do this because of performance issues but as long as you keep the rest of the plugin simple and optimise your images well I think you should be fine.

**EDIT**

Still think this is the only way to achieve the effect. I would probably keep the html as you have it with all the background image as single entities but I would use js to clone them, position them and move them. Example:

```
var windowSize = $(document).width();
var elementSize = (windowSize - $('#header').width())/2;

$('#bg_1').addClass('bg_1').css('background-position','right top').width(elementSize+'px').clone().css({'left':'auto','right':'0','background-position':'left top'}).insertAfter('#bg_1');

$('.bg_1').each(function(){$(this).pan({fps: 3, speed: 2, dir: 'right'})});
```

Naturally this needs some work but I tried running this in firebug on you site and it achieves the effect more-or-less. The positioning of the background images is off but I imagine that is because of the pan function having started. If the pan function automatically positions the background images before it starts moving them then the effect you want will be even harder to achieve.

You'd also be left with the issue of the background behind the rounded corners, although in at the top I think this would just be blue anyway.

Comment: I like where you're coming from.  That's what I'm keeping it at right now.  You should check it out now, it looks pretty cool: www.marioplanet.com

I'm gonna leave the question open to see if I can find out how I can do this without two instances, even though I'll probably stick with just one.